# Migrating MVC2 to MVC3: problem with MVCFutures

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to migrate an MVC2 project to MVC3 - i've followed the instructions within the release notes and the app will compile, but the project depends on a few helpers located inside the previous MVCFutures and tosses:

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'SubmitImage' and no extension method 'SubmitImage' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My solution includes a Lib folder, inside of which is:

MVCFutures\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll

Do i have an upgrade option here?

Comment: Do you have an assembly binding redirect for MVC 1.0-2.0 to 3.0?

Comment: I've verified that I have the specific bindingRedirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that your MVC futures binary is located in a Lib folder. Make sure that:

1. Your project has an assesmbly reference to that library
2. The MvcFutures dll is being copied to the bin folder
3. Your web.config has an assembly reference to MvcFutures

Could you also clarify if the exception you are seeing is when compiling your app in Visual Studio (because you are using MVC futures methods in your controllers or data models) or when you access your application in the browser (because you are using futures in your views).

Btw, an upgraded version of MVC Futures that targets MVC 3 will be released soon.

Update: The source code for MVC 3 Futures is already available on codeplex: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781 so you can compile it yourself.

Comment: [defers to the resident authority] - the questions lead me to conclude i'm best off rebuilding the project from a new slate of views. in the long run most efficient. thx

Answer (score 1):

use this tools for upgrading:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx

Answer (score 1):

@justSteve,
First off, you can download the MVC3 source from codeplex, which includes the MvcFutures code, and just build the new futures assembly yourself.
However, I'd be willing to bet that your problem is a missing using statement somewhere.

Make sure your page has a using namespace statement for Microsoft.Web.Mvc.

If you're trying to migrate to Razor (which you didn't say, but just in case), you can put a namespace reference in the web.config file contained in your Views folder (to avoid having to include the using statement in each of your views), like this:

```
   <system.web.webPages.razor>
     <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
     <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
           <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
           <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Helpers" />
           ...
        </namespaces>
     </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 0):

For upgrading your views you might want to try this from Telerik...

https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter

...it will convert your webforms views to razor.

Regards

Paul